# LaunchPad totally disorganised after reboot OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, launchpad

Running Yosemite 10.0 with a clean erase and install, when I reboot, all my launchpad apps are totally disorganised, folders and un-official apps disappears...

After reorganizing the layout twice, I don't want to keep sorting my launchpad every time I restart my Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to: User directory > Library > Application Support > Dock > there, you might have a file with a strange name finishing by .db - you can do this in finder with the Go menu and paste or type the string shown below:

[image]

2. Put this file into the trash, but don't empty the trash, just in case.
3. Just restart the Mac. The Launchpad must be reinitialize, that's mean you have to remake the arrangement of all your apps, the same way at your first Lion's installation. Voilà!
4. If you have problems after the reboot, you can restore the file from trash to the correct location - replacing any new file that was created and then contact Apple support in that case:

[From Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3214380?start=15&tstart=0)

Comment: Same problem here that appeared initially after upgrade from 10.8 to 10.12 and now persists in 10.13. Unfortunately, the suggested solution did not work for me.